# How to create linear regression from starting point?

Tags: statistics

How would you calculate linear regression from a starting point? The graph below shows the actual linear regression line (yellow/orange), but what if I wanted to start linear regression calculation at $y = 25$ like the black line? The black line (drawn by me) was just a rough estimate of what the actual linear regression from the starting point 25 might look like.

Ofcourse you could add your starting value to the $b$ of $y = mx +b$, but all that would do is shift the line.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply subtract $25$ from each of the data points to get $\bar{y}_i$ and then do a one-parameter linear regression of the form 
$$
\bar{y} = k x
$$
Having done this, the original points are fit by 
$$
y = k x + 25
$$

---

**LATER**

I believe the least-squares value of $k$ is given by the weighted average of the shifted data points, that is, 
$$
k = \frac{\sum (y_i-25) x_i}{\sum x_i}
$$

Comment: Thank you, not 100% sure I understand what you are saying, but i'll try and program it and see if that helps. Is there anyway you could provide an example?

Comment: $\bar{y}_i$ do you mean average of the $y_i-25$?

Comment: No, I simply mean the data points shifted by 25 so that you are doing afit to $y=kx$ rather than $y=kx+ b$ with some non-zero $b$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand 100% now.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the point here is that you want to estimate an OLS regression with parameter constraints. In this case, if you estimate
$$y=b+m x,$$
that is, estimate coefficients $b$ and $m$ to find the best fitting line to your data, then you want to constrain $b=25$ (guaranteeing $y=25$ at $m=0$) and hence only estimate $m$ with this constraint.

Good statistical packages should let you do this. In Stata, you can do this via [rcnsreg](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rcnsreg.pdf). Whatever package you use, look up "parameter constraints" and it should get you some answers.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I have not started my 2nd year where I will be taking statistics classes so I do not really understand what you are saying. Mark Fischler explained one way to do it, but I was hoping he could elaborate more on his notation with an example.

Comment: See the edit above.